# Copying a file using xcopy path invalid

Tags: batch-file, copy, xcopy

I trying to copy from on file to another using a batch file, however i get the error in valid path.

```
SET DatabaseBackupPath=C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.DBNAME\MSSQL\Backup
SET NewDatabaseBackupPath=‪‪C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents

xcopy "%DatabaseBackupPath%\%NewestFile%" "%NewDatabaseBackupPath%"
```

This is the ouput for `%NewDatabaseBackupPath%` = `"ÔÇ¬ÔÇ¬C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents"`

Can someone explain why all these characters exist and a possible solution?

Comment: Try for the second line `SET "NewDatabaseBackupPath=‪‪%USERPROFILE%\Documents"`

Comment: @mofi thanks fro the reply, unfortunately this still thinks the file path is `ÔÇ¬ÔÇ¬C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents`

Comment: Perhaps your batch file is not stored as ANSI text file but as a Unicode file?

Comment: @aschipfl How would i get around this? very new to creating batch files?

Comment: This depends on your text editor; I'd open your batch file with Notepad using its "File»Open..." dialog; as soon as you are selecting your batch file, its encoding should be displayed in the related field (at least on Windows Vista or later); if it is not *ANSI*, you could change it when manoeuvring to "File»Save As..."...

Answer (score 1):

There is doubled **harmful** character `[U+202A]` in line `SET NewDatabaseBackupPath=…` and its UTF-8 representation `0xE280AA` i.e. decimal sequence `226`, `128`, `170` is the same as that `ÔÇ¬` string in OEM code pages

```
CP850 US & Western Eu
CP852 Central Europe
CP857 Turkic
```

Try <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>226</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>128</kbd>. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>170</kbd> in an open `cmd` window or check using my [*Alt KeyCode Finder* script](https://superuser.com/a/1047961/376602)

Picture taken from [Google Chrome Extension Unicode Analyzer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/unicode-analyzer/pipjflhdnjcdflbkmoldkkpphmhcfaio)

[image: U+202A]

Comment: thanks for the information very useful, so how can i fix this issue?